# mysql: count sum of column created via sql

Tags: mysql

i show first and last log for each day from user 1 ,

alo i calculate the time differnece between first and last log.

so what i want is to calculate total sum of  time difference  something like

**SUM(total)**

here is what i run

```
SELECT id,device,userid,time, MIN(time) as Min, MAX(time) as Max, TIMEDIFF(MAX(time), MIN(time)) as total
FROM records WHERE userid='1' GROUP BY DATE(time)
```

result  [image]

so i want to get like
totalsum = =25:31:47

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can use your current query results in a [Derived table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html) and calculate the sum.
- Also, you will need to first convert the time to seconds using [TIME_TO_SEC()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec) function, and after doing the `SUM`, you will need to reconvert it back to time by using [SEC_TO_TIME()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time) function.

Try the following:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC(derived_t.total) ) ) AS total_time_diff
FROM 
(
 SELECT TIMEDIFF(MAX(time), MIN(time)) as total
 FROM records 
 WHERE userid='1' 
 GROUP BY DATE(time) 
) AS derived_t
```

Comment: i get this number 248206

how can i see hours:minutes:seconds

Comment: @Gloytoshtyqo check the updated answer. it should work now for you